# Any way to reference MySQL "AS" values within the query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

in the following query, I sum up all the Sale Items of all the Sales in the given range. Included in this summary is "sumOfCost" and "sumOfPrice", I'd like "sumOfProfit" too. The problem is, as they're only "AS" variables, I'm not sure how to reference them, and my attempt of "... Blah AS blah, sumOfPrice - sumOfCost = sumOfProfit ..." sadly didn't work!

Here is my query:

```
SELECT  Sales.SaleID, 
        Sales.StaffID, 
        Sales.CustomerID, 
        Sales.Timestamp, 
        Sales.Refunded, 
        Sales.PaymentType, 
        Staff.Forename AS staffForename, 
        Staff.Surname AS staffSurname, 
        (   
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Quantity, ' x ', Name) 
            FROM SaleItems 
            WHERE SaleItems.SaleID = Sales.SaleID
        ) AS itemList, 
        (
            SELECT sum(Cost*Quantity) 
            FROM SaleItems 
            WHERE SaleItems.SaleID = Sales.SaleID
        ) AS sumOfCost, 
        (
            SELECT sum(Price*Quantity) 
            FROM SaleItems 
            WHERE SaleItems.SaleID = Sales.SaleID
        ) AS sumOfPrice 
FROM    Sales 
        INNER JOIN Staff 
            ON Sales.StaffID = Staff.StaffID 
WHERE   Sales.Deleted = '0' 
ORDER   BY Timestamp DESC 
LIMIT   0, 15
```

Apologies for the length of the query, I've struggled before to optimise it better but right now I'm only looking to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why you need it? If you want to make condition, you can use HAVING clause [ instead of WHERE ], and I believe you can use them in ORDER

Comment: @mkk he wants to calculate the result, based on the subqueries.

Comment: istead of using dependant subqueries which take more time use joins which are faster

Comment: Re-edited OP, not sure why but someone changed my query?

Comment: @Redgie to make the query clearer

Comment: But it changed the content? The produced values are used as they are output, by changing the name of some of the values the page the query is used in no longer works?

Comment: @Redgie no, it only changed the formmating, not the original content

Comment: @redgie Don't use the subquery method. Just write out the calculation long hand. And please don't write your queries on one line. It's so hard to read. That's why I reformatted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative to solve this problem is by wrapping the whole query with a *subquery*,

```
SELECT  *,
        sumOfCost - sumOfPrice AS sumOfProfit
FROM
    (
        SELECT  Sales.SaleID, 
                Sales.StaffID, 
                Sales.CustomerID, 
                Sales.Timestamp, 
                Sales.Refunded, 
                Sales.PaymentType, 
                Staff.Forename AS staffForename, 
                Staff.Surname AS staffSurname, 
                (   
                    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Quantity, ' x ', Name) 
                    FROM SaleItems 
                    WHERE SaleItems.SaleID = Sales.SaleID
                ) AS itemList, 
                (
                    SELECT sum(Cost*Quantity) 
                    FROM SaleItems 
                    WHERE SaleItems.SaleID = Sales.SaleID
                ) AS sumOfCost, 
                (
                    SELECT sum(Price*Quantity) 
                    FROM SaleItems 
                    WHERE SaleItems.SaleID = Sales.SaleID
                ) AS sumOfPrice 
        FROM    Sales 
                INNER JOIN Staff 
                    ON Sales.StaffID = Staff.StaffID 
        WHERE   Sales.Deleted = '0' 
        ORDER   BY Timestamp DESC 
        LIMIT   0, 15
    ) s
```

---

By the way, they are called `ALIAS`.

The reason why `ALIAS` can't be used for calculation on the same level where they were defined is because the server executes the `FROM` clause before the `SELECT` clause. The `ALIAS` are on the `SELECT` clause, here's the full SQL Order of Operation:

- FROM clause
- WHERE clause
- GROUP BY clause
- HAVING clause
- SELECT clause
- ORDER BY clause

For better performance issue, I'll rather using `JOIN` than `subqueries`.

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  Sales.SaleID, 
        Sales.StaffID, 
        Sales.CustomerID, 
        Sales.Timestamp, 
        Sales.Refunded, 
        Sales.PaymentType, 
        Staff.Forename AS staffForename, 
        Staff.Surname AS staffSurname, 
        COALESCE(a.itemList, '') itemList,
        COALESCE(b.sumOfCost, 0) sumOfCost, 
        COALESCE(c.sumOfPrice, 0) sumOfPrice,
        COALESCE(b.sumOfCost, 0) - COALESCE(c.sumOfPrice, 0) AS sumOfProfit
FROM    Sales 
        INNER JOIN Staff 
            ON Sales.StaffID = Staff.StaffID 
        LEFT JOIN 
        (   
            SELECT SaleID, GROUP_CONCAT(Quantity, ' x ', Name) itemList
            FROM SaleItems 
            GROUP BY SaleID
        ) a ON a.SaleID = Sales.SaleID
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT SaleID, sum(Cost*Quantity) sumOfCost
            FROM SaleItems 
            GROUP BY SaleID
        ) b ON b.SaleID = Sales.SaleID
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT SaleID, sum(Price*Quantity) sumOfPrice 
            FROM SaleItems 
            GROUP BY  SaleID
        ) c ON c.SaleID = Sales.SaleID
WHERE   Sales.Deleted = '0' 
ORDER   BY Timestamp DESC 
LIMIT   0, 15
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
SELECT  Sales.SaleID,
        Sales.StaffID,
        Sales.CustomerID,
        Sales.TIMESTAMP,
        Sales.Refunded,
        Sales.PaymentType,
        Staff.Forename AS staffForename,
        Staff.Surname AS staffSurname,
        COALESCE(a.itemList, '') itemList,
        COALESCE(a.sumOfCost, 0) sumOfCost,
        COALESCE(a.sumOfPrice, 0) sumOfPrice,
        COALESCE(a.sumOfCost, 0) - COALESCE(a.sumOfPrice, 0) AS sumOfProfit
FROM    Sales
        INNER JOIN Staff
            ON Sales.StaffID = Staff.StaffID
        LEFT JOIN
        (  
            SELECT      SaleID,
                        GROUP_CONCAT(Quantity, ' x ', Name) itemList,
                        SUM(Cost*Quantity) sumOfCost,
                        SUM(Price*Quantity) sumOfPrice
            FROM SaleItems
            GROUP BY SaleID
        ) a ON a.SaleID = Sales.SaleID
WHERE   Sales.Deleted = '0'
ORDER   BY TIMESTAMP DESC
LIMIT   0, 15
```

Comment: This may well be the best option. Thanks for explaining why the original concept wouldn't work :) It's annoying I'll have to restructure the query mind you...

Comment: @Redgie I'll be posting the `JOIN`ed version of this, and to which I think has a better performance.

Comment: @Redgie see my update, you don't need to wrap the whole query with a subquery, and you can now use the columsn directly.

Comment: @Redgie you're welcome. `:D` By the way, welcome to StackOverFlow!

Comment: @Redgie check this query if the result is the same. I tried to minimize it. [<< CLICK HERE >>](http://pastebin.com/J2mCcfMQ) so I can paste it here

Comment: It appears the results are indeed the same, thank you AGAIN! :)